# how to draw bitmap on osm/mapsfrge

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm developing a little application for android to display GPS location with a bitmap. I used some example codes with Google maps, but I have to make it with maps forge. Unfortunately I haven't found any example codes or anything about how to write this drawing operation. 
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the souce for the ItemizedOverlay class, in particular it's draw() and onDrawitem() methods: [ItemizedOverlay.java](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedOverlay.java).

That class draws a Drawable **marker** to the canvas.

You could use similar code to draw your own Drawable.
Or you could implement the ItemizedIconOverlay class, add a collection of one or more OverlayItems to the ItemizedIconOverlay and use the [OverlayItem](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/OverlayItem.java) setMarker method to set a Drawable as an icon.